# How to convert vectors to an orthonormal set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors.

$$(1,2,3) \text{ and } (2, -1, 0)$$

I am being asked to convert these to an orthonormal set.

Now what I think to do is take the square root of the sum of the squares.

So for the first vector:

$$\sqrt{1+4+9}$$

Then divide the answer by the original vector elements.

First vector:

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{9}{\sqrt{14}})$$

But I am being told this is incorrect.

Looking for a formula.

Comment: You have to ensure that your vectors are orthogonal as well, i.e. their scalar product must be equal to 0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process . It's a standard algorithm that produces an orthonormal family of vectors

Comment: You should divide the original vector $(1,2,3)$ by $\sqrt{14}$, but you put $9$ on the last denominator.

Comment: $v_1 = (1,2,3)$, $v_2 = (2,-1,0)$. Please note that the dot product of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is zero which means they are already orthogonal. You just have to normalize the vectors by dividing out their sizes ( $\sqrt14$ and $\sqrt5$ resp.)

Answer (score 1):

A set is orthonormal if it's orthogonal and the magnitude of all the vectors in the set is equal to 1.

The dot product of (1, 2, 3) and (2, -1, 0) is 0, hence it is orthogonal. You can normalize a vector by multiplying it to it's unit vector by the formula $$u = \frac{v}{||v||}$$ where v is a vector being normalized. This will in turn change the magnitude of your vector into 1.